# Is there a solution to implement an "low-speed" scrubbing on Exoplayer2?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm working on an application who needs some precision when scrubbing on the videoplayer, in order to get an image from the video.

The problem is, the timebar is too imprecise.
I'm looking to implement a solution like the native iOS player, when you scrub and you swipe down your finger to slow down.

-> https://lifehacker.com/how-to-control-the-audio-and-video-scrubbing-speed-on-y-5811660

If you have a solution, it would be really cool.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Exoplayer cannot do this for streaming. A similar discussion has been seen regarding AVPlayer - to allow the described behaviour for streaming, and some have suggested  making snapshots which would also not be close to your want of getting the same behaviour as on the example you have provided.

If you are looking for this kind of experience I would recommend heading over to [movi.ai](https://movi.ai) to get your hands on our cross platform solution with this ready out of the box.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your answer. Streaming is more a feature, we can use local storage. I don't think we're going to move from exomplayer for now but i'll take a look on your solution :)